# Centos-bind: Reverse DNS failed

Tags: reverse-dns, dns-hosting

Hi Server fault member,

I need to setup a reverse DNS for my client. There have 3 IP ranges on the rDNS server.

The server system is Centos 6.5 with bind 9

Let me describe my situation.

1. I have a old DNS server for A record & dns pointing.
2. I setup two server for the rDNS, master and slave.
3. After i configured all the named.conf, in-appr file. I can start the named service with no error.
4. I am the owner of those IP address

> ```
> Mar 17 17:01:27 nsx1 named[11200]: running
> Mar 17 17:01:27 nsx1 named[11200]: received control channel command 'reload'
> Mar 17 17:01:27 nsx1 named[11200]: loading configuration from '/etc/named.conf'
> Mar 17 17:01:27 nsx1 named[11200]: reading built-in trusted keys from file '/etc/named.iscdlv.key'
> Mar 17 17:01:27 nsx1 named[11200]: using default UDP/IPv4 port range: [1024, 65535]
> Mar 17 17:01:27 nsx1 named[11200]: using default UDP/IPv6 port range: [1024, 65535]
> Mar 17 17:01:27 nsx1 named[11200]: no IPv6 interfaces found
> Mar 17 17:01:27 nsx1 named[11200]: sizing zone task pool based on 9 zones
> Mar 17 17:01:27 nsx1 named[11200]: reloading configuration succeeded
> Mar 17 17:01:27 nsx1 named[11200]: reloading zones succeeded
> ```

It seems like no problem.

But when i use dig to test the IP address, there was no answer section at all.
eg. dig -x abc.abc.abc.xyz

What's going on? Hope someone can help me. I searched so many solution but no luck.

This is one of my in-appr file (all located at the /var/named folder)

```
> $TTL 3600       ; 1 hour 
> @       IN      SOA   my-master-server.domain slave-dns-server (
>                 2015012701      ; serial
>                 3H              ; refresh
>                 15M             ; retry
>                 1W              ; expire
>                 1D              ; minimum
>                 )
> 
> xxxxxxx.in-addr.arpa.        IN     NS      master-dns-server-hostname
> xxxxxxx.in-addr.arpa.        IN     NS      slave-dns-server-hostname  
> 
> 0       IN      PTR     xxxxxxx-0.xxxxxxx 
> 1       IN      PTR     xxxxxxx-1.xxxxxxx
> 2       IN      PTR     xxxxxxx-2.xxxxxxx 
> .......
> 255     IN      PTR     xxxxxxx-255.xxxxx
>
```

This is my named conf.

```
> options {
>         # listen-on port 53 { 127.0.0.1; my master dns server-ip; };
>         listen-on port 53 { any; };
>         # listen-on-v6 port 53 { ::1; };
>         directory       "/var/named";
>         dump-file       "/var/named/data/cache_dump.db";
>         statistics-file "/var/named/data/named_stats.txt";
>         memstatistics-file "/var/named/data/named_mem_stats.txt";
>         # allow-query     { localhost; };
>         allow-query     { any; };
>         allow-transfer  { slave-server-ip; };
>         # recursion yes;
>         recursion no;
> 
>         dnssec-enable yes;
>         dnssec-validation yes;
>         dnssec-lookaside auto;
> 
>         /* Path to ISC DLV key */
>         bindkeys-file "/etc/named.iscdlv.key";
> 
>         managed-keys-directory "/var/named/dynamic"; };
> 
> logging {
>         channel default_debug {
>                 file "data/named.run";
>                 severity dynamic;
>         };
>         # Logging file for fail2ban
>         channel security_file {
>                 file "/var/log/named/security.log" versions 3 size 30m;
>                 severity dynamic;
>                 print-time yes;
>         };
>         category security {
>                 security_file;
>         };
>};

>zone "." IN {
        type hint;
        file "named.ca";
>};

>include "/etc/named.rfc1912.zones";
>include "/etc/named.root.key";
>include "/etc/named/first-iprange.in-addr.arpa.zone";
>include "/etc/named/sec-iprange.in-addr.arpa.zone";
>include "/etc/named/third-iprange.in-addr.arpa.zone";
```

One of my zone file located at /etc/named folder.

```
zone "third-ip.in-addr.arpa" IN {
    type master;
    file "third-ip.in-addr.arpa.db"; 
    allow-update { none; };
};
```

Thanks a lot.

Comment: I very strongly recommend that you put the real IP addresses and files in this question.  DNS questions in particular often hinge on very small details that are lost in redacting.

Comment: Is the zone correctly delegated to your nameserver? Also I'm missing trailing dots, although that may be due to your redacting.

Comment: All the problem were solved.
It was so amazing. I just give it up a week.

I didn't change anything, the reverse DNS start to work after i re-install the named service.

thanks for all you guys comment and advice.